# Can Lazy propogation be implemented for division queries?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree, lazy-propagation

How can lazy propogation be implemented for segment tree in which we have two types of queries, one for finding maximum element in a given range and other is to divide elements in a given range by a number( not necessarily same for all elements like maybe each element is divided by its smallest odd factor or something of that sort)?

Comment: It can be implemented but the update process would be costly.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in O(logn) complexity?